# Regular Expression Match for a Title

Tags: c#, regex

I need to use C# to write a Regular Expression for a title, here is the requirement:

1. Title is required (length > 0);
2. Maximum 256 characters (length <= 256);
3. No character is forbidden, but whitespace only is illegal (the title ONLY containing whitespaces is illegal);
4. No leading or trailing whitespaces;

I have already have this:

```
^.{1,256}$
```

So how can I meet the rule 3?

**EDIT:**

1. Explained rule 3 more clearly;
2. I added rule 4 from Mario's answer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: hmmm, sometimes, the Regular Expression has slightly different syntaxes for different languages, so I thought the tag `C#` is necessary in the title.

Comment: We use tags for that on [so]. The title can be the title. Sort of a [so] "Separation of Concerns" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd skip regular expressions completely, because you can just hardcode string cleanup and validation in two simple steps:

- Use `String.Trim(null)` to remove all leading/trailing whitespaces.
- Compare the length of the remaining string.
- Uppercase the first character (if you want to).

This works, because a name consisting of whitespaces only would be trimmed to 0 length.
Also this avoids using titles such as `"         Let's go!"`.

Comment: Techincally, that's not what he asked for; this would accept 256 character surrounded by whitespace

Comment: IMO it really depends whether you'd like to accept names such as `  test  ` (or prefer them "fixed up"). If you want to keep the leading/trailing spaces, you could just do the length check first, then determine whether what's left after `Trim()` is still longer than 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `(?=pattern)`

```
@"^(?=.*\S).{1,256}$"
```

The `(?=pattern)` asserts that the specified pattern exists immediately after this location.

So, the regex matches if and only if after the beginning of the string, it matches the pattern `.*\S` and if the whole string matches the pattern `^.{1,256}$`

Comment: @SLaks In the third rule OP explain that only whitespace is illegal.

Comment: That's not what he means.  He only wants to reject strings that are _entirely_ whitespace.

Comment: @SLaks I hadn't interpreted the rule this way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a zero-width assertion:

```
@"^(?=.*\S).{1,256}$"
```

`(?=.*\S)` matches any sequence of characters that ends in a non-whitespace character, but does not affect the rest of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Though my own answer fits my question, but the credit should still go to the other guys (I either upvoted and chose as the correct answer), because I edited my question after their answer.

=====================

I finally came up a pure regex solution (without any extra steps)

```
^(\S|\S.{0,254}\S)$
```

(though I don't understand why the parentheses `()` are important)

The following test cases pass:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckTitleTest()
    {
        // Empty
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTitle(@""));

        // A whitespace
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTitle(@" "));

        // Multiple whitespace only
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTitle("  \t \n \u1680"));

        // Leading whitespaces
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTitle("  \tabc"));

        // Trailing whitespaces
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTitle("abc\t "));

        // Leading and trailing whitespaces
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTitle("  \tabc\t "));

        // Too long: 257 character
        Assert.IsFalse(CheckTitle(@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/*"));

        // A normal title
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTitle(@"This is a normal title"));
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTitle(@"This is a normal title."));

        // 256 characters
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTitle(@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"));

        // A very simple title
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTitle(@"A"));
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTitle(@"!"));
        Assert.IsTrue(CheckTitle(@"\"));
    }
```